Proof verification - Infinity/maximum norm is a norm
Background knowledge
There are three fundamental properties of a norm.
Let V be a real vector space. Let $|\cdot|$ be a norm then $|\cdot|$ satisfies these three properties:

(Positivity): $|x|\geq0$ and $|x|=0 \implies x=0$, $\forall x \in V$
(Homogenity): $|\lambda x|=|\lambda||x|$,$\forall x\in V$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$
(Triangle inequality): $|x+y|\leq |x|+|y|$, $\forall x,y \in V$

Answer
Let's now check whether the defined norm satisfies these properties. In this case $V=\mathbb{R}^n$.

(Positivity): $||x||_\infty=\max_{1\le i \le n}|x_i|\geq0$ since $|x_i|\geq0$. Assume $||x||_\infty=\max_{1\le i \le n}|x_i|=0\implies x_i=0 \implies x=0$. Therefore positivity is satisfied.
(Homogenity): $||\lambda x||_\infty=\max_{1\le i \le n}|\lambda x_i|=|\lambda|\max_{1\le i \le n}|x_i|$. Therefore homogeneity is satisfied.
(Triangle inquality): $||x+y||_\infty=\max_{1\le i \le n}|x_i+y_i|\leq\max_{1\le i \le n}|x_i|+\max_{1\le i \le n}|y_i|=||x||_\infty+||y||_\infty$. Therefore the triangle inequality is satisfied.

Since all three properties are satisfied, the defined norm is a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Questions

Is my method correct? Are there any extra steps that would make my reasoning more clear?
Would saying the norm defined with min be a norm? Would it if it was sup/inf?


For homogenity I would add that the second inequality works because $|\lambda|\geqslant 0$ and for the triangle inequality, I would add that $|x_i+y_i|\leqslant |x_i|+|y_i|\leqslant \|x\|_{\infty}+\|y\|_{\infty}$ so $\|x+y\|_{\infty}\leqslant\|x\|_{\infty}+\|y\|_{\infty}$.
The $\min$ would not give you a norm, for instance take $x=(1,0,\ldots,0)$ then $\min|x_i|=0$ but $x\neq 0$.
As for the $\sup/\inf$, it's the same thing as $\max/\min$ because you're working on finite sets so they are the same thing.

That makes sense @Tuvasbien. Thank you for the quick reply. So basically this norm would be the same if I replaced "max"  for "sup" because the set that I am taking the max of is finite and will always have a max, which means max=sup. In the case that instead of $\mathbb{R}$ I have the space of functions. Saying "sup" would make more sense since that space can be infinite. Is that correct?

@Nayirus Exactly, the analogous norm on the set $\mathscr{C}b(X,\mathbb{R})$ of bounded functions $X\to\mathbb{R}$ for some set $X$ would be $|f|{\infty}=\sup_{x\in X}|f(x)|$.
